# How to feed input() function by writing to sys.stdin

Tags: python

In my gui application (PyQt5), the `input()` function is waiting for input in the background, i want to feed the output of lineEdit (when it is pressed) to the `input()` function. I tried writing the output to sys.stdin like so:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
sys.stdin = StringIO(command)
```

the problem is `input()` function cant take the input. any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import threading
from io import StringIO


class App():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.ui_file = 'app.ui'
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.ui_file))
        self.window.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect)
        self.window.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(self.enter)

    def enter(self):
        # take the input from lineEdit
        command = self.window.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.window.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.input(command)
        # feed the command as an input to the input() which is waiting
        sys.stdin = StringIO(command)

    def exec(self):
        self.window.show()
        self.app.exec_()

    def print(self, text):
        self.window.textBrowser.append(text)

    def connect(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        t.start()

    def run(self):
        self.print('Password: ')
        # input() is waiting for input
        password = input('Password: ')
        print('password is', password)


def main():
    app = App()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you *using* `input` in the first place?

Comment: @user2357112 im converting a cli application to a gui application. I wanted to use signals and stuff but that doesnt work. This is the only solution i can think of.

Comment: Did you add this code to the existing application, or are you running that application with something like `subprocess.run()`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes i did. No im not using subprocess module.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Barmar question updated.

Comment: Where is the `App.input()` method? You need to assign `sys.stdin` *before* the application calls `input()`. Changing `sys.stdin` while `input()` is waiting is too late, it's waiting for the terminal then.